# PHPUnit keeps skipping tests - Win7-64, XAMPP, Yii

Tags: php, selenium, yii, phpunit

PHP unit is skipping all of its tests when running.  I am running a development environment.  Here is my environment:

- Windows 7 Pro 64bit
- Apache 2.4
- PHP 5.4.4
- PHPUnit 3.7.0
- Selenium 1.2.8
- Yii 1.1.10

Everytime I run the functional (or any tests) for Yii, I get the following output.

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\mm\protected\tests>phpunit --verbose functional
PHPUnit 3.7.0 by Sebastian Bergmann.

Configuration read from C:\xampp\htdocs\mm\protected\tests\phpunit.xml

SSSSSS

Time: 12 seconds, Memory: 3.50Mb

There were 6 skipped tests:

1) SiteTest::testIndex
Could not connect to the Selenium Server on localhost:4444.

C:\xampp\php\phpunit:46

2) SiteTest::testContact
Could not connect to the Selenium Server on localhost:4444.

C:\xampp\php\phpunit:46

3) SiteTest::testLoginLogout
Could not connect to the Selenium Server on localhost:4444.

C:\xampp\php\phpunit:46

4) SiteTest::testIndex
Could not connect to the Selenium Server on localhost:4444.

C:\xampp\php\phpunit:46

5) SiteTest::testContact
Could not connect to the Selenium Server on localhost:4444.

C:\xampp\php\phpunit:46

6) SiteTest::testLoginLogout
Could not connect to the Selenium Server on localhost:4444.

C:\xampp\php\phpunit:46
OK, but incomplete or skipped tests!
Tests: 6, Assertions: 0, Skipped: 6.

C:\xampp\htdocs\mm\protected\tests>
```

**Note:** Never received the could not connect to Selenium server before and didn't change a thing.  Still posting this question and investigating.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Is the Selenium JAR still running?  Is it on localhost?

Comment: How do i verify if selenium is running? I installed it with PEAR before...

Comment: You need a selenium server, which is separate from the PHP library:  http://seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.html

Answer (score 2):

RTM. There is a chapter named [Functional Testing](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/test.functional) in the official Yii guide. It begins with:

> Before reading this section, it is recommended that you read the Selenium documentation.

The chapter ends with the following note, with a big mark in the left margin:

> Tip: Before running functional tests, the Selenium-RC server must be started. This can be done by executing the command java -jar selenium-server.jar under your Selenium server installation directory.

Comment: Very insightful Mytskine! You answered all of my questions :D!

Comment: @CGSmith105 might be good to accept this answer as the correct answer.